# Can't connect store to another page

Tags: react-native, redux

I'm new to Redux so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I am using a counter which works on the first page

First page:

```
'use strict';

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import Counter from '../components/counter';
import * as counterActions from '../actions/counterActions';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Router, Scene, Route, ActionConst } from 'react-native-router-flux';

import Home from './Home';


class Routing extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    const { state, actions } = this.props;
    console.log(state.count); //This returns 0 just like it's supposed to
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Scene hideNavBar="true" key="root">
          <Scene counter={state.count} key="home" component={Home} initial={true} animation="false" duration='0' />
        </Scene>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}

export default connect(state => ({
    state: state.counter
  }),
  (dispatch) => ({
    actions: bindActionCreators(counterActions, dispatch)
  })
)(Routing);
```

Home page:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as counterActions from '../actions/counterActions';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';



export default class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {};
  }


  render() {
    const { state, actions } = this.props;
    return (
        <Text>
          {state.counter}
        </Text>
    )
  }
}


export default connect(state => ({
    state: state.counter
  }),
  (dispatch) => ({
    actions: bindActionCreators(counterActions, dispatch)
  })
)(Home);
```

The connect on the Home page throws me the error `Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope'`

I thought it could be something to do with `React Native Router Flux` because I'm using Scenes but it only happens when I try to connect the store to the Home page.

Comment: You have 2 `export default`s for the `Home` component. Only one `default export` is allowed per file. `const` is block-scoped, so assigning `const state =...` in `Routing`'s `componentDidMount` makes `state` not accessible inside `render`, am I right?

Comment: You are right I can't access it inside render.. But how am I supposed to connect Home without using export default? If I don't use it it doesn't give the error but I still can't access this.props.counter.

Comment: I removed export default from the class Home instead and that worked thanks a lot!

Comment: But unfortunately state.count does not exist somehow in Routing.

Comment: I don't know what exactly the problem was but I pulled an older version with git and now I can see it as 0. If you could put it as an answer please I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of pointers for your code.

1. There are currently two `export default`s for the `Home` component. Only one default export is allowed per file. You will want to expose the result of `connect()`, so change

   `export default class Home extends Component {`

   to

   `class Home extends Component {`.
2. Since `const` is *block-scoped*, it only exists within the current block. Defining `state` and `actions` in `Routing`'s `componentDidMount` means they aren't available inside `render`. Just move those definitions inside the `Routing` component's `render` method:

   ```
   render() {
     const { state, actions } = this.props;

     return (
       <Router>
         <Scene hideNavBar="true" key="root">
           <Scene counter={state.count} key="home" component={Home} initial={true} animation="false" duration='0' />
         </Scene>
       </Router>
     )
   }
   ```